# could instead of would

Tags: modal-verbs

1) I would have called you, but I didn't know your number.

2) I could have called you, but I didn't know your number.

Can I use 2 in place of 1? Do they mean same?

Comment: could goes to a possibility. Would is a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** after reading OP's comment to this answer.

The two sentences in the question are saying different things. In the first case **would** is *certain*, but in the second case **could** remains a *possibility*. So the second sentence reads like an excuse.

Referring to the examination question asked in comment, you might think the same applies, but it is a different situation because passing the examination is something outside of your control (only studying and attending are), so using **would** in the first sentence is wrong. I suggest the valid sentence is

> I could have passed the exam if I had studied hard.

Comment: Thank you. Are not these two sentences equivalent?  1 )  I would have passed the exam if I had studied hard 2) I could have passed the exam if I had studied hard

Comment: That is rather different. You have moved the goal posts, and they are not equivalent.

Comment: @user6789 I updated the answer.

Comment: If would "means" certain and "could" means possibility then isn't 1) means that speaker is certain about the outcome if he had studied hard. So 1 is valid sentence but has different meaning than 2.

Comment: Studying hard does not guarantee passing an exam. It can turn out that the subject was just too difficult.

Comment: "I would have passed the exam if I had studied hard" is expressing certainty. It is grammatically and semantically correct, but may be factually wrong. The speaker is expressing confidence or certainty that may not be deserved.

"I could have passed the exam if I had studied hard" is expressing the possibility of passing in that situation, acknowledging that their lack of study had prevented them from passing.

Comment: @SamBC doesn't my answer say that? The original question asks if they mean the  same, and they don't.

Comment: While I deal with embarrassment over not noticing the date on the question... Your answer says that, in the exam example, only could would be correct. I was trying to clarify that it depends what sense of "correct" you mean.

Comment: @SamBC they are both grammatically correct.

Comment: @Weather Vane Yes, they are, and semantically valid. But you said "the valid sentence is", suggesting that it was the only valid one of the two that were posited by user678 9. You might think that a person would never be factually correct to say they would have passed an exam, but that doesn't change the validity of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The first case is assuring someone that, had you had their number, you would have called.

The second makes no such assertion, but points out that because you didn't have their number, it was impossible for you to call.

This is because *would* expresses (potentially subjective) certainty (when used in this sort of situation - there is some variation due to the history of the word), while *could* expresses possibility.